# Randomized Control of Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, random

I am trying to randomize the order of a time series data set. I generated my data as:

```
    ts5 = RandomFunction[FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[.5], {0, 999, 1}]
```

Now I need to create a randomized control of this data: essentially, I need to treat the y and t values as their own lists and only randomize the y values while keeping the t values in the same order (0-999).

However, I have not found a way to separate the data, and the built in random functions are unable to preform this task (or so says my Google Fu).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Your `ts5` data is wrapped in a [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object. You can use `First@ts5["Paths"]` to get a `{{t0, y0}, {t1, y1}...}` regular list of pairs.

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB! I will update my post with my new attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the path from the [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) object, then isolate the $y$ values and produce a random permutation using [`RandomSample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html); finally add back the $t$ values:

```
ts5List = First@ts5["Paths"];
scrambled = Transpose@{ts5List[[All, 1]], RandomSample[ts5List[[All, 2]], Length[ts5List]]}

ListPlot[scrambled]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @FoxForceFive glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Working from what @MarcoB suggested, I came up with:

```
    ts5randomized = RandomSample[ts5["Values"]];
    ts5randomizeSeries = TimeSeries[ts5randomized, {0, 999, 1}]
    ListLinePlot[ts5randomizeSeries]
```

This appears to be what I needed. Thanks again @MarcoB!